# Tuple to dictionary in python by using text file

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a code which returns a dictionary with the
names as the keys and the corresponding values which are tuples of
numbers.  The first number after the name controls how many numbers are
in the corresponding tuple (the numbers included in the tuple are taken
from the left to right).  For example, the line of text `"Ali 6 7 6 5 12 31 61 9"` has 6 as the first number after the name and this line of text
becomes the dictionary entry with the keyword "Ali" and the
corresponding value is a tuple made up of the next six integers "Ali":
(7, 6, 5, 12, 31, 61).

This is the film I'm taking the code from

```
  Bella 5 2 6 2 2 30 4 8 9 2
  Gill 2 9 7 54 67
  Jin 3 26 51 3 344 23 
  Elmo 4 3 8 6 8
  Ali 6 7 6 5 12 31 61 9
```

the expected output is

```
Ali : (7, 6, 5, 12, 31, 61)
Bella : (2, 6, 2, 2, 30)
Elmo : (3, 8, 6, 8)
Gill : (9, 7)
Jin : (26, 51, 3)
```

so i've done like this

```
   def get_names_num_tuple_dict(filename):      
   file_in = open(filename, 'r')
   contents = file_in.read()
   file_in.close()
   emty_dict = {}
   for line in contents:
      data = line.strip().split()
      key = data[0]
      length = int(data[1])
      data = tuple(data[2:length + 2])
      emty_dict[key] = data

   return emty_dict
```

But I'm having this error
    length = int(data[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Can anyone please help? That will be really helpful. I'm a bit weak with the dictionary as learning for the first time.

Comment: Have you even tried to use the debugger?

Comment: Didn't learn about that function....where is it in the python program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following code:

```
def get_names_num_tuple_dict(filename):      
   emty_dict = {}
   with open(filename) as f:
      for line in f:
         data = line.strip().split()
         key = data[0]
         length = int(data[1])
         data = tuple(data[2:length + 2])
         emty_dict[key] = data

   return emty_dict


print(get_names_num_tuple_dict('my_filename'))
```

Output:

```
{'Bella': ('2', '6', '2', '2', '30'), 'Gill': ('9', '7'), 'Jin': ('26', '51', '3'), 'Elmo': ('3', '8', '6', '8'), 'Ali': ('7', '6', '5', '12', '31', '61')}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what happens:

```
contents = file_in.read()
```

Reads your file into string. When you loop over this string it will go character by character and give you `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Basically try using:

```
for line in file_in:
    data = line.strip().split()
        ...
```